# PHP Efficiency: Is it better to include at beginning of script or in function?

Tags: php, performance

I am creating a project management system using a custom PHP MVC framework.  I have a controller class that is responsible for handling projects.  Naturally, one of the functions in my controller is  createProject().  When a project is created, I need to send out an email so I also have a mailer class.

Is it more efficient to include('/model/Mailer.class.php'); at the beginning of the createProject() function, or at the beginning of the controller class containing the createProject() function and why?

My thought was that it would be more efficient to include it at the beginning of the createProject() function so that way it doesn't have to always be included when other functions are called that don't require it.

Comment: It's more efficient to use an [autoloader](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php), so that class files are only loaded when they're actually needed

Comment: typical given two choices you pick a third!. :)

Comment: You should check out the [php-fig standards](http://www.php-fig.org/) to help you further with best approaches and design practices for a solid PHP framework

Comment: There's a bit of a trade-off here (without using autoload). Requiring them up-front will guarantee that you include all of those files regardless of whether you need them. Including them in each function may necessitate the use of require_once (or include_once) to avoid a fatal error. That, in turn, will slow you down while it checks whether the file has been loaded every time the function is called....  TLDR: use autoload like @MarkBaker says

Comment: Wich PHP MVC framework are you using ?

Comment: @Isaac I am using a slightly modified version of [this tutorial](http://phpro.org/tutorials/Model-View-Controller-MVC.html).  The server I am required to use has an older version of php so I am forced to use __autoload() instead of spl_autoloader.  The only other major change I made to the example is that I use a URL parser to break the query string into key => value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

If you include the file at the beginning of class like:

```
include ('theFileClass.php');
class SomeClass{
    //code ...
}
```

you can maintain the code more easily. On the other hand, if you include the file like this:

```
class SomeClass{
    public function someMethod(){
        include ('theFileClass.php');
        //code ...
    }
}
```

sometimes is considered a bad practice.

However, you will get a better performance if you use an autoload strategy and your code will be more readable and maintainable. Use [spl_autoload_register](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) instead of `__autoload`.

A little example:

```
//bootstrap.php
<?php
class Framework{
    //code ...
    public function createProject(){
        //code ...
        $mail = new MailerClass();
        //code ...
    }
    //code ...
}

spl_autoload_register(function($class){
    require_once 'path'. $class .'.php';
});
```